# Testing the setting of a private variable

Tags: java, testing

Say we have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
     private String results;
     private DataFetcher fetcher;

     public void setFetcher(DataFetcher fetcher)
     {
         //handle exceptions, empty results, etc. 
         this.fetcher = fetcher;
     }

     public void acquireResults(int id)
     {
         this.results = fetcher.fetchData(id);
     }

     public String printResults()
     { 
         return "Your results: " + this.results;    
     }

}
```

We want to check that when we call `acquireResults` that the private variable `results` is being set properly.

How would I test this?

I could add a getter, just so I can access `results` at testing.

Or I could use reflection to access it, (but that seems like overkill?).

Or perhaps you want to argue that I shouldn't be testing it / there is something wrong with my design.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, creating a public getter, creating a protected getter and than testing the subclass which is exposing the protected method or just using reflection - all valid options in some cases.

But if this is (as I am guessing) a simplification of some complex system you should think about changing the design a bit; ask yourself what are you trying to test;

1. setting a value to "results"?
2. calling "fetcher"?
3. calling "fetcher" with the right input?

Perhaps you need 3 tests. 
Perhaps you need more classes with public methods that do one specific task and they can be tested directly.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to test, depends on resources and time that you have.

You can have getters and put print statements,

you can use asserts

If you have access, I'd vote for using a debugger, and running a program that uses your code in question, setting a breakpoint, and inspecting the actual running program. Then your code stays 'clean' of cruft that you'd have to do for the other debugging strategies (putting asserts, and debugging methods, and print statements all over).